# Compare function variable against array loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I'm attempting to compare the value passed through the function (val) with items in an array (data.category) in order to replace my hard-coded 'cat1' and 'cat2' in the if/else statement. What I ultimately want to do is assign the appropriate $scope.catName and $scope.info for the appropriate value associated in the array.

How do I modify my code to iterate and compare?

```
$scope.changeRankingView = function(val){
    var categoriesArray = data.category;
    var categoriesArrayLength = categoriesArray.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < categoriesArrayLength; i++) {
        if(val === 'cat1'){
          $scope.catName = data.category[0].name;
          $scope.info = data.category[0].info;
        }
        else if(val === 'cat2'){
          $scope.catName = data.category[1].name;
          $scope.info = data.category[1].info;
        }
    }
  };
```

Comment: @developer033 -- sorry first time using SO. I added question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not completely sure I followed, but I think this would do what you are asking:

```
$scope.changeRankingView = function(val) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.category.length; i++) {
        if(val === data.category[i]){
          $scope.catName = data.category[i].name;
          $scope.info = data.category[i].info;
        }
    }
 };
```

I used `data.category` directly, because it didn't seem like `categoriesArray` was adding anything useful.

Comment: Thank you for your help here. It was hard for me to phrase this into a question. For my own education, how could I have rephrased the question to be more clear? @DWright

Comment: You actually phrased it quite well.  Your code was so close to the solution, I just wasn't sure if I was missing something else.